# Alpha Vantage Python API for Fundamentals

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to access fundamental data from Alpha Vantage's python API, but it's not working. My imports:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.fundamentaldata import FundamentalData
```

The TimeSeries functions work well, e.g. the following works fine:

```
ts = TimeSeries(key=av_api, output_format='pandas')    
data, metadata = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol='IMB', outputsize='full')
```

But the Fundamentals calls don't work. When I call:

```
FundamentalData.get_income_statement_annual(symbol='IBM')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _format_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've read through the documentation, and the tutorials don't have examples using the fundamentals API call. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source of getting the annual income statement, and it requires specifying self, so in this case, I was able to get it correctly by giving the ts with the APIkey set.

```
ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas') 
FundamentalData.get_income_statement_annual(ts,symbol='IBM')

  fiscalDateEnding  ...    netIncome
 date                                            ...             
 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000       2020-12-31  ...   5590000000
 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001       2019-12-31  ...   9431000000
 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002       2018-12-31  ...   8728000000
 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003       2017-12-31  ...   5753000000
 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004       2016-12-31  ...  11872000000
 
 [5 rows x 26 columns], 'IBM')
```

Comment: I got to the answer by referring to the source in the hint in Google Collaboratory. The location of the source can be found [here](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/blob/master/alpha_vantage/fundamentaldata.py). `def get_income_statement_annual(self, symbol):`

Comment: What part of the source code, e.g. which lines, showed you that you needed to "specify self"? Also, how did you know that passing in 'ts' would work to specify the self? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, here it is.`def get_income_statement_annual(self, symbol): `

Comment: Ah, got it: because it says self in the function arguments, you know you need to define self. That was the missing link for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that if you don't want to send the API key every time, you can set it once, and then just use the symbol:

```
fd = FundamentalDat(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
```

then the API calls work fine:

```
fd.get_income_statement(symbol='IBM')
```